# Long action is locking renderer process

Tags: user-interface, vue.js, electron, vuex

I have a function that I'm calling in a component template. It reacts on changes in a vue-select component.

```
<v-select
  v-model="model"
  :options="eventList"
  :placeholder="currentEventTitle"
  v-on:input="selectedEvent"
  taggable
  label="name"
></v-select>

...

</template>
<script>

...

methods: {
   ...mapActions({
      selectedEvent: "selectedEvent"
   })
}
```

This `selectedEvent` action that is being dispatched contains many HTTP calls, commits to the store, and calls to other actions. The issue is that once this has been called, the UI completely locks and doesn't update until about halfway through the function.

How should I call an action that will commit (mutate), and dispatch other actions, and not lock the UI?

### Update

The problem has disappeared in our production build and only exists when we have development mode enabled.

Comment: I suggest thinking about webworkers - so you can push workload to an own "thread"

Comment: The thing is the API calls don't block the UI thread when calling them without vuex. It was only after committing the results to the vuex store, calling the APIs through a _dispatch_, that this became an issue.

Comment: Hmm then I guess it is due to big data coming from HTTP calls and reactivity. I had a case with 2k+ items and solved it by referencing only a subset of those in vue/vuex - storing the data in a global or component non reactivly.

Answer (score 0):

If vuex observer/ reactivity is the reason for the ui block one can simply freeze big objects to prevent reactivity:

```
actions = {

   // ...,
   assignBigData(context, data){
      //...
      // mutate data
      const clone = {...data}
      context.commit('commiter', Object.freeze(clone))
   },
   selectedEvent: async function(context, ...args){

     const response = await request()

     context.dispatch('assignBigData', Object.freeze(response))
   }
}
```